# When setting up a maven workflow on github I keep getting this error: "The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]"

Tags: java, maven, github

Here is the link to the github page with the issue

https://github.com/YasoJan/startingOutWithJava/runs/1720361130?check_suite_focus=true

[image: Here is a screenshot of the error message I receive]

Comment: What's your pom.xml look like and where is it in your project?

Comment: I copy and pasted my java code into a sub directory in the main/master. So I don't have one. How do I create one?

Comment: Is this written using Eclipse?

Comment: Im using an online IDE because I can only use my chromebook for the next week

Comment: I would suggest downloading Eclipse and getting to know that IDE.  There are a few industry standards, and Eclipse is one of the most used ones.  Good to know if you plan to do this as a job.  It's free and easy to setup.  I would also read up on Maven and what it does.  An essential part of learning java is building a Java project.  That is exactly what Maven does.

Answer (score 0):

You need a pom.xml.

If you need Springboot initializr will greatly help you :
https://start.spring.io/

Most IDE (Eclipse, IntelliJ, ...) have a generation feature.
It should be in something like "new" -> "maven project".

I strongly advise to take one or two hour to read some doc on Maven.

Comment: Can I create a pom.xml file from an online IDE?

Comment: Hard to say.  I don't use online IDEs.  The pom.xml file is a Maven file that tells it how to to build the project.  It might be a jar file or a war file or whatever.  Another nice thing about it is that it can also download all of the java dependency files.  Read up on Maven.  It's an essential tool in the industry today.

Answer (score 0):

pom.xml file is a build file that defines how the project will be built.  In Eclipse, you can right-click on the project and click CONVERT TO MAVEN.  Here's some help

https://crunchify.com/how-to-convert-existing-java-project-to-maven-in-eclipse/

Comment: Can I create a pom.xml file from an online IDE?